# The import java.util.List collides with another import statement error

Tags: java, selenium

Im testing with selenium in java but I have a problem.

This is my code:

```
List <WebElement> frame = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
```

Problem is: "Multiple markers at this line
            - The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments 
     "

I tried this solution but not working.

```
import java.util.List;
```

This problem output is:

```
The import java.util.List collides with another import statement
```

What will I do ?

Comment: You've apparently imported another List class

Comment: You can use fully qualified names in your code. So instead of `List<Webelement>` write `java.util.List<Webelement>`

Comment: Remove the `import` of `java.awt.List`, which is probably there somewhere. You can't import two types with the same base name.

Comment: there is an error with the part of the code you have not shown to us....